# Is it possible to pass a block of code as a macro argument?

Tags: c

I'd like to wrap some lines of code with some boilerplate code, so should I do it by passing multiple lines of code as a macro argument like so:

```
#define safeRun(x) if (ValidationOK()) {x} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    safeRun(
        foo();
        bar();
    )
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: An example describe that what you search : [useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790590/pass-block-instruction-as-macros-argument-in-c/42808062#42808062)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182877/is-it-ok-to-use-a-code-block-as-an-argument-for-a-c-macro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As written, your code will run foul of comma operators (but not, as previously claimed, commas in a function argument list).

Assuming you use C99, you can evade even that problem with variable arguments in the macro:

```
#define safeRun(...) if (ValidationOK()) {__VA_ARGS__}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    safeRun(
        foo(a, b),
        bar(c, d);
    )
}
```

Now, as far as the preprocessor is concerned, there are 2 arguments to the macro, separated by the commas, but they are handled as you want.  Here's the `gcc -E` output:

```
# 1 "x3.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x3.c"


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (ValidationOK()) {foo(a, b), bar(c, d);}



}
```

Whether what you're proposing is a good idea is a separate discussion; these are the mechanisms that will more or less make it work.

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to also to 'fake' curly braces? Ideally I'd like it to look like `safeRun{...}` rather than `safeRun(...)`.

Comment: No; the preprocessor expects parentheses and not braces. You can use braces inside the argument list if you really want to, though.

Answer (score 2):

As @Potatoswatter says you can use backslashes:

```
#define safeRun(x) \
  [Validation code]; \
  if (ValidationOK()) \
      {x} \
  [Finishing code]; \
```

But this can be a problem if you use it in this way:

```
if (x)
  safeRun(y);
else
  ...
```

To fix the problem:

```
#define safeRun(x) \
  do { \
      [Validation code]; \
      if (ValidationOK()) \
          {x} \
      [Finishing code]; \
  } while(0);
```

Comment: I saw code with a #define followed by a do...while and came here to confirm this is what was going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\` character to "escape" newlines inside the macro definition. Use variadic macro arguments to support commas inside the argument containing the lines of code. (This feature is part of C99, but also exists in many noncompliant compilers.)

```
#define safeRun(...) \
[Validation code]; \
if (ValidationOK()) \
    {__VA_ARGS__} \
[Finishing code]; \
/* bumper line to support last backslash, leave empty! */
```

Note that there cannot be whitespace between the backslash and the newline.

Standard caveat: macros are the leakiest form of encapsulation; use any other construct if possible.

Comment: You may want to use the double hash to avoid problems or a trailing coma ##__VA_ARGS__.

Comment: @ant2009 Not sure what you mean. That's a GCC extension, far as I recall, but it only serves a purpose when passing `__VA_ARGS__` to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Function-like macros are very bad for a number of reasons. A much better way to solve this is to use real functions.

```
start_safe();
  foo();
  bar();
stop_safe();
```

Comment: But then I'd have to handle the `if` conditions seperately in the main code, which start to defeat the purpose of defining these macros to tidy up.

Comment: @MiloChen If you remove the semicolons and use "regular" macros `START_SAFE foo(); bar(); STOP_SAFE` then it is a valid design pattern, with the advantage of avoiding `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @MiloChen Then the main problem might just be that the macros are superfluous to begin with. You could also solve this with a function taking two function pointers as parameters, but that feels needlessly complicated as well. Keep the code simple!