# How to pass arbitrary code block to C macro as a param

Tags: c++, macros

I want to create a macro that will accept arbitrary code block as its parameter like

```
FOR_VECTOR( type, vect, code_block ) \
  for( vector<type>::iterator i=vect.begin(); i!=vect.end(); ++i ) { \
    code_block; \
  }
```

The problem is the code block in parameter, which may contain arbitrary number of `,` and  `)` characters.

Is there any good solution?

Comment: You mean besides "don't do that" ? Are you familiar with *functions* ?  Functors? Or in C++11, *lamdas* ?

Comment: What he ^^ said. Apart from that, parenthesize it. The preprocessor is smart enough to recognize parentheses.

Comment: OK, I will consider all the alternatives, but I want such a macro :) And I can not parenthesize full code block, only one expression.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182877/is-it-ok-to-use-a-code-block-as-an-argument-for-a-c-macro

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions.

If you need only one expression (not a full-fashioned code block) - you can just enclose it in `(` and `)`

```
FOR_VECTOR( int, v, (func(i,1)) )
```

will work - `(func(i,1))` is treated like single macro argument

Another partial solution is [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), if your preprocessor supports them.

You can define macros

```
#define COMMA ,
#define LPAR (
#define RPAR )
```

and use them to form your code block insted of real `(` `,` and `)`

```
FOR_VECTOR( int, v, func LPAR i COMMA 1 RPAR )
```

It is not very readable though.

Or you can do a trick with commenting out quotes of a string literal after macro substitution:

```
FOR_VECTOR( type, vect, code_block ) \
  for( vector<type>::iterator i=vect.begin(); i!=vect.end(); ++i ) { \
    /code_block/; \
  }

FOR_VECTOR( int, v, *"*/ func(i,1); proc(i,2); /*"* )
```

Comment: I weep for anyone other than you that needs to maintain that code. :)

Comment: Is this even valid? All of the compilers I've tried give an error.
And this shouldn't produce a `/*` token anyway. Preprocessor doesn't paste tokens when it substitutes macro arguments. You have to write `/##code_block`, but that wouldn't produce a valid token: `error: pasting "/" and "*" does not give a valid preprocessing token`.

Comment: @Hedede The example was taken from actual valid C++ code, compiled near 2007. The trick looks very "dubious" in terms of any reasonable code style convention, and after lambda-functions were introduced into C++, I think there is absolutely no point in doing that. I am going to update the answer to tell about it.

Answer (score 5):

As @mas.morozov mentioned, you can use variadic macros:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define FOR_VECTOR( type, vect, ... ) \
  for( std::vector<type>::iterator i=vect.begin(); i!=vect.end(); ++i ) { \
    __VA_ARGS__ \
  }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    FOR_VECTOR(int, v, {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    })
}
```

You can play with it online here: https://godbolt.org/z/oLWV-z

I found that solution here: https://mort.coffee/home/obscure-c-features/

You can also make a more generic `FOR_CONTAINER` macro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define FOR_CONTAINER( container, ... ) \
  for( decltype(container)::iterator i=container.begin(); i!=container.end(); ++i ) { \
    __VA_ARGS__ \
  }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    FOR_CONTAINER(v, {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    })
}
```

Try it here: https://godbolt.org/z/9Gzqja