# pass block instruction as macro's argument in C

Tags: c, macros

I don't know if that is possible, I want to pass a block of instructions in macro like an argument.I will show you an example:

```
#define ADD_MACRO(size, BLOCK){ for(int i=0; i<size; i++){\
                                    BLOCK} }
```

what do you think about it?

thanks for help

Comment: It's a horrible thing to do, but it should work - what happened when you tried it ?

Comment: This is an "XY problem". You most definitely don't want to invent evil macros like this. Although C allows all manner of weird crap, it doesn't mean that you should do it. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Should work, but is a bad idea. Better use a function taking a function pointer for the block. Or why pass the block at all? After all, from a coding-style view this is all opinion-based.

Comment: All of them are right! it will make debugging hell too.

Comment: What dogmatic views some people have... If it works and makes code better readable you should do it. That's what macros are for in the first place, making code better readable.

Comment: @Ctx do you honestly think it would make the code more readable to use this macro?

Comment: @Ctx Using macros to invent your own secret macro language makes code less readable. Other C programmers can read C, they cannot read super-secret-macro-language. Function-like macros in general is the very last resort.

Comment: @JeremyP The OP clearly stated that this is just an example, PoC if you want to put it that way.

Comment: @Ctx I'm not questioning the legitimacy of the question, only your opinion about whether it makes code more readable.

Comment: @Lundin You can write uncomprehensible code one way or the other. A macro like that can support or harm readability, this is not a matter of the general concept

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, I think, having code in a macro can be used in a way, which makes a program better readable if the circumstances are appropriate.

Comment: @Ctx In case you have one opinion and the vast majority of the professional C programmer community around the world has another, it is no longer opinion-based. Avoiding obscure, function-like macros is industry standard praxis. There's no point to even argue about it, because you know this as well as everyone else.

Comment: @Lundin I would need some evidence that your precious opinion is representative for this vast number of professionals then ;))

Comment: @Lundin - Lua, GTK(GObject) and many other libraries *do have* obscure function-like macros. Obscurity is an opinion of course, because it is convenient. As of vast majority, there are two you and two us. I can upvote Ctx comments to balance that feeling if you want. Oh, Perl, I forgot Perl! And Python,of course. And Qt.

Comment: @Ctx Pick any industry coding standard. CERT-C: [prefer inline or static functions to function-like macros](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/PRE00-C.+Prefer+inline+or+static+functions+to+function-like+macros). MISRA-C:2012 Directive 4.9. The Linux kernel coding style chapter 12. And so on. Pick whichever applies to the kind of applications you work with.

Comment: @Lundin: While I'm with you about not getting too fancy with macros (I learned it the hard way long time ago), the wide usage of boost and the boost preprocessor library shows there is a broad interest. Does not mean I support what is shown in the question.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion, I posted a version below which replaces the need for multiple unsafe, messy macros, with one single safe, messy macro.

Comment: wawww great debate, tks for interesting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a block of code as a macro argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353104/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-block-of-code-as-a-macro-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem with the given macro is that it doesn't handle commas in the `BLOCK`. Commas are tolerated by a variadic macro parameter:

```
#define ADD_MACRO(size, ...) do { for(int i=0; i<size; i++){\
                                      __VA_ARGS__} } while(0)
```

(Also, common practice is to enclose statement macros in `do … while(0)` to force the user to include a semicolon.)

(Of course, the original problem may have a better solution. The preprocessor is a blunt instrument. This is the preprocessor solution to the stated question.)

Comment: `#define ADD_MACRO(size, ...) do { ... } while (0)`, please

Comment: I don't recommend the elipsis `...` approach, as in case you substitute several parameters you will have in the substituted text the parameters separated by commas, probably not the desired effect.

Comment: @LuisColorado `__VA_ARGS__` may be considered as several parameters separated by commas, or equivalently as one parameter which contains commas. Both cases are the intended usages of the language feature. Sometimes it's preferable to enclose a "one parameter with commas" in parentheses, like `ADD_MACRO( 5, (printf("%d ", i);) );`, but IMHO it's overkill here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, you're right in that, and more, the preprocessor will not eliminate the parenthesis, so you'll get the wrong result whe trying to protect the parameter commas, and your solution would be better than mine (which was no one at all), but in other side, the varargs macro feature is GNU specific and not addressed by any of the standards, IMHO.

Comment: @LuisColorado `__VA_ARGS__` comes from the C99 standard. GNU had a different syntax. The extra parentheses must be stripped, of course; this requires an additional macro.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, if we want to use this method in function or void, is it the same story, might we make some changes ?

Comment: @wolfgunner Maybe it's better to ask a new question with more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply showing a block into the macro, or by using a variadic macro as suggested in another answer. However, I wouldn't recommend using macros for this purpose, as it tends to make the code less readable, more error-prone and harder to read/maintain.

Instead, for generic programming, consider using function pointers corresponding to the desired functionality.

Another option is to use the C11 `_Generic` macro to create type safe, generic code. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void int_increase (int* item)
{
  (*item)++;
}

void char_increase (char* item)
{
  (*item)++;
}

void int_print (int* item)
{
  printf("%d ", *item);
}

void char_print (char* item)
{
  printf("%c", *item);
}

void int_clear (int* item)
{
  *item = 0;
}

void char_clear (char* item)
{
  *item = '\0';
}

void int_traverse (int* data, size_t size, void(*action)(int*))
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    action(&data[i]);
  }
}

void char_traverse (char* data, size_t size, void(*action)(char*))
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    action(&data[i]);
  }
}

#define do_something(data, size, action)  \
  _Generic((data), int*  : int_traverse,  \
                   char* : char_traverse) \
  ( (data), (size), _Generic((data), int*: int_ ## action , char*: char_ ## action ) )

int main (void)
{
  int int_data [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  do_something(int_data, 5, increase);
  do_something(int_data, 5, print); 
  printf("\n");
  do_something(int_data, 5, clear);
  do_something(int_data, 5, print); 
  printf("\n");

  char char_data [] = "ABCDE";
  do_something(char_data, 5, increase);
  do_something(char_data, 5, print); 
  printf("\n");
  do_something(char_data, 5, clear);
  do_something(char_data, 5, print); 
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 5 6
0 0 0 0 0
BCDEF
```

Simply add more of the similar kind of functions if you need to use other types.

Comment: Sidenote: `_Generic` is a bit problematic about compatible types. There is a defect report which handles this subject in detail. Briefly: current implementations of e.g. gcc and clang disagree about how to handle certain qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

thks for all, especially Potatosmatters, so I follow your directives and I would like to resume your answer into small code that can be useful for the others:

```
#define CALL_MACRO(size,instructions){ for(int i=0;i<size; i++){\ 
                                           instructions ;} }
......
 //put whatever you want into 'instructions'
 CALL_MACRO(100,for(int y=0; y<3; y++){ (inst1);
                                        (inst2);..} );
 CALL_MACRO(100,(other inst1);(other inst2);.. );
```

So the result of CALL_MACRO depends on what you insert as instructions.