# Any trick for simpler definition of multiline C macros?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, generic-programming

I am trying to write some reusable generic type-safe code in C, using macros, similar to how [klib](https://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/implementing-generic-hash-library-in-c/) works:

```
#define Fifo_define(TYPE) \
   \
   typedef struct { \
       TYPE *head; \
       TYPE *tail; \
       size_t capacity; \
   } Fifo_##TYPE, *pFifo_##TYPE; \
   \
   inline Fifo_##TYPE * Fifo_##TYPE##_init(size_t capacity) { \
       Fifo_##TYPE * fifo = calloc(1, sizeof(Fifo_##TYPE)); \
       TYPE * data = calloc(capacity, sizeof(TYPE)); \
       fifo->head = data; \
       fifo->tail = data; \
       fifo->capacity = capacity; \
   }

// define macros       

#define Fifo(TYPE) Fifo_##TYPE
#define Fifo_init(TYPE, capacity) Fifo_##TYPE_init(capacity)
```

And then I just use it with any type parameter:

```
Fifo_define(int32_t);
...
Fifo(int32_t) *myFifo = Fifo_init(int32_t, 100);
```

However, writing this is rather convoluted and error prone, with no IDE editor support (IntelliSense), so I wondered if there are any tricks which might allow me to (perhaps) add a few defines and then include the file, without having to end each line with `\`?

Something like:

```
// no idea how to do this, just checking if similar concept is possible

#define FIFO_TYPE int
#define FIFO_NAME Fifo_int

#include <generic-fifo.h>

#undef FIFO_NAME
#undef FIFO_TYPE
```

And I would somehow get all the right `struct`s and functions. The problem is that there is a lot of parameter concatenation in these macros, so I am not sure if this can be done in a simpler manner than the first snippet?

Comment: I estimate it to be possible, I have seen this kind of macro-magic. However, you state (rephrased) you want to reduce the number of lines ending in "\" and I understand that to be a (commendable) desire for readability. Also I think that there will be side effects, e.g. the need for using "#undef". (I have a superstition that using undef is evil, i.e. useage-error prone.) I estimate that the macro-magic would not make things more readable, on the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really recommended in this case, but you can do something like what you want to achieve with [X-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro):

```
#define SUPPORTED_TYPES \
  X(int)                \
  X(double)             \
  X(char)

#define X(TYPE)         \
   typedef struct {     \
       TYPE *head;      \
       TYPE *tail;      \
       size_t capacity; \
   } Fifo_##TYPE, *pFifo_##TYPE;
SUPPORTED_TYPES
#undef X

#define X(TYPE)                                          \
inline Fifo_##TYPE * Fifo_##TYPE##_init(size_t capacity) \
{                                                        \
  Fifo_##TYPE * fifo = calloc(1, sizeof(Fifo_##TYPE));   \
  TYPE * data = calloc(capacity, sizeof(TYPE));          \
  fifo->head = data;                                     \
  fifo->tail = data;                                     \
  fifo->capacity = capacity;                             \
}
SUPPORTED_TYPES
#undef X
```

But this didn't really improve the situation all that much. It got rid of the need for a single, ugly `Fifo_define` macro, so you can split up the code in several sections. But the macro mess remains.

---

I would recommend some completely different approach. Two suggestions:

- Handle the type-generic things in the classic C way, in run-time. Use callbacks. Keep track of the used type with an enum, if needed.
- C11 `_Generic` allows all kinds of type safety tricks and can be used to phase out such messy macros. [Example that implements "functors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790590/pass-block-instruction-as-macros-argument-in-c/42791772#42791772). The macro itself is kept minimal and the different implementations for various types is typed out. (That's usually what you end up doing anyway, when you do type-generic programming.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using complex macros, consider using m4 instead of the C pre-processor. [m4 is similar to the C pre-processor but is much more powerful](http://mbreen.com/m4.html) and can do things like have multiple lines without a line continuation character.

Using code generators like m4 is called *[meta-programming](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-metaprog1/index.html)*.

Using m4 in C can be accomplished by treating it as a pre-pre-processor [like this](https://www3.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/Tru64-Unix/HTML/APS32DTE/M4XXXXXX.HTM):

```
% grep -v '#include' file1 file2 | m4 > outfile
% m4 file1 file2 | cc
```

Since m4 works in a similar way to the C pre-processor at the basic level, it will generally convert any ordinary C macros correctly in addition to supporting its own advanced features.